# How to test that filter was triggerd on an action execution with PHPUnit

Tags: unit-testing, yii, filter, phpunit

I have an Yii Controller with an action and filter bound to it, like this:

```
...
public function testAction() {}

public function filters() {
    return array(array('CMyFilter +test'));
}
...
```

I can't figure out how to test simple fact that CMyFilter is invoked each time testAction() is executed.

My test looks like this:

```
$filter = $this->getMockBuilder('CMyFilter')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->setMethods(array('preFilter'))
        ->getMock();

$filter->expects($this->once())
        ->method('preFilter')
        ->will($this->returnValue(true));
```

and it fails with a message «Expectation failed for method name is equal to  when invoked 1 time(s).
Method was expected to be called 1 times, actually called 0 times»

Actualy i could call Yii::app()->getRequest()->isAjaxRequest() instead of using a filter, and mock CHttpRequest in my test, but i find it a bit odd.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think the your problem because of the your action name "testAction". The name conventions for actions should be in the this format:

```
public function actionName(){
}
```

So change your action name to actionTest()

Comment: Thank you, but this is not the case. It's my typo - the real code looks a bit different.

Comment: @not null, May I ask you to clean me about your question? Describe it more? Thank you.

Comment: I have actionTest() and filter CMyFilter. I want to test the fact that  this filter executes every time actionTest() is executed. So in case this filter ocasionaly removed from config (filters()) specifying filters to actions, my test would fall.